# Slim templates, custom DOCTYPE

Tags: ruby, doctype, slim-lang

i have a page with this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

and converting it now to slim template format, bu slim has no such `doctype` in presets, and i suspect there should be way to specify custom one. Now i use `|`:

```
|<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "...skip...>
html
 ....
```

But it rendered without line break symbol after `doctype` line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "...skip...><html ...
```

Which is undesired, any way to put them on separate lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a line break at any point in the template, just add this line:

```
= "\n"
```

The "=" command in Slim executes the given Ruby code and appends it to the buffer. In this case, the Ruby code is simply a newline character.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need the `|` character, Slim allows [inline HTML](http://rdoc.info/github/stonean/slim#Inline_html____HTML_style_) for directly including HTML, and that includes doctypes. This doesn’t help with the formatting though, there is still no line break after it.

The [doctypes are actually managed in Temple](https://github.com/judofyr/temple/blob/v0.5.5/lib/temple/html/fast.rb#L5-22), which Slim uses. You could change this to add a custom doctype to get the behaviour you want. This does involve messing with Temple’s internal data so you need to be a little careful, especially when upgrading, as the internals may have changed.

The hash in question is has been [frozen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze), so you can’t just add a new entry to it. You can however [`dup`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) it, add an entry to the duplicated hash, and assign the new hash back to the constant. This will cause Ruby to generate a warning as you shouldn’t normally reassign constants this way.

```ruby
new_hash = Temple::HTML::Fast::XHTML_DOCTYPES.dup
new_hash['rdf'] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">'
Temple::HTML::Fast::XHTML_DOCTYPES = new_hash
```

Now you can use `rdf` as if it was a predefined doctype in Slim.

```
doctype rdf
html
```

This produces:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html></html>
```

If you want to avoid seeing the warning, set `$VERBOSE` to `nil` before changing the constant (make sure you change it back afterwards).

```ruby
begin
  old_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
  Temple::HTML::Fast::XHTML_DOCTYPES = new_hash
ensure
  $VERBOSE = old_verbose
end
```

(You could turn this into a method that accepts a block. If you’re using Rails it’s already been done for you with [`silence_warnings`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings).)

Comment: When i remove `|` then i getting runtime error: '''Unknown line indicator'''

Comment: Thank you for solution, but i prefer to avoid hacky solutions, because it makes app hard to maintain finally

Comment: @Dfr what version of Slim are you using? It looks like the inline HTML  was added in 1.3.1: https://github.com/stonean/slim/blob/v1.3.1/CHANGES#L3